# I heard about the new ZombieLoad vulnerability. How do I protect my Mac?

Tags: security, malware

I don't want my data to be vulnerable to the new MDS issues discovered on Intel processors. What can I do? Is my credit card information safe?

Comment: Oh, and your credit card information is seldom safe. Use Apple Pay or the Privacy app exclusively.

Answer (score 3):

For the official word, and how to mitigate the Intel issues on your Mac, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210108

Realistically, if you've updated to macOS 10.14.5, use Safari as your web browser and only run applications downloaded from the App Store, you have nothing to worry about. Otherwise, you may want to review this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210119

Apple has moved EXTREMELY quickly to handle this situation. Kudos to them!

I suspect Chrome, Firefox and other browsers will be updated soon. If you're extremely paranoid, you will need to disable hyperthreading (at a 40% performance hit).

Comment: "Extremely" quick? It has CVE-***2018***-12130 and it looks as if Intel had some fixes ready for around 5 months now for some. It is just coordinated well with going public with it.

Comment: How about...faster than Microsoft and many Linux distros, faster than Google Chrome, faster than Firefox.

Comment: Well. What about openness in communication Creation Date:
21-FEB-19 https://www.suse.com/de-de/support/kb/doc/?id=7023736 or http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1905.1/05371.html I'd say that being slower than what we got would have been even more unacceptable. Granted that the fault comes this time again mainly from Intel, the whole design process and responsibility scheme in this development and sales model is *severely broken.* I mean 40% down-hit? After all those other bugs? I now want to see quite a lot of money from Intel.

Comment: @LangLangC Well, given that it was published on the same day everyone is basically on the same level. Agreed, not "extremely" quickly–but not slow either.